# Como ordeno un array en Visual Basic con negativos

Tags: array, vb.net

Tengo un código en consola que ordena un array, pero solamente si el número es positivo, si ingreso un negativo solo coloca en 0, también, el segundo array debe quedar vácio, pero si yo coloco un 0 en la posición del array que es mayor en ese momento y hay otra posición con el mismo número, ambos se convierten en 0, ¿cómo puedo solucionar estos dos problemas?

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim Array(4) As Double 'Primer Array.
    Dim Orden(4) As Integer 'Segundo Array.
    Dim j As Integer = 0 'Autoincremento de el segundo Array.
    Dim Mayor As Integer 'Número mayor temporal.

    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese 5 números enteros.")

    For i = 0 To Array.Length - 1 'Finaliza en la ultima posición del Array.
        Console.Write(i & "> ") 'Se ingresan los números.
        Array(i) = Console.ReadLine 'Se almacena en la posición en cestión.
        If Array(i) Mod 1 = 0 Then 'Si el número es entero no pasa nada.
        Else 'Se el número es decimal i decrece en 1.
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite un número entero.")
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next

    Do While j < 5 'Hasta que j valga 5.
        For i = 0 To 4
            Mayor = Max(Mayor, Array(i)) 'Se calcula el número mayor temporalmente.
        Next

        For i = 0 To 4
            If Mayor = Array(i) Then 'La posición del array que sea igual a mayor pasará a ser 0.
                Array(i) = 0
            End If
        Next

        Orden(j) = Mayor 'La posición actual de Orden es rellenada con el valor mayor.
        j = j + 1 'j incrementará en 1.
        Mayor = -32768 'Mayor pasa a valer lo menor posible, por si los números son negativos.
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("Array inicial") 'Se imprime el primer Array.
    For i = 0 To 4
        Console.WriteLine(">" & Array(i))
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Array ordenado") 'Se imprime el segundo Array.
    For i = 0 To 4
        Console.WriteLine(">" & Orden(i))
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para salir...")
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos... un sistema de ordenamiento muy 'curioso'... pero debes saber que 0 es mayor que cualquier número negativo, aclarado esto analizamos el codigo:

En la siguiente parte, estan todos los problemas...

```
    For i = 0 To 4
        If Mayor = Array(i) Then 'La posición del array que sea igual a mayor pasará a ser 0.
            Array(i) = 0
        End If
    Next
```

Si cuando encuentras el número mayor lo conviertes en 0, los negativos que existan, siempre serán menores que ese 0, por lo que nunca se tomaran en cuenta. La solución en este caso sería poner el menor número posible en vez del 0.

```
        For i = 0 To 4
            If Mayor = Array(i) Then 'La posición del array que sea igual a mayor pasará a ser 0.
                Array(i) = -32768
            End If
        Next
```

Para el segundo problema, el de evitar que si hay dos o más números iguales los converta todos, solo tiene que añadir un 'exit for' para que cancele la busqueda cuando encuentre el primero de los números y no continue con los demás...

```
        For i = 0 To 4
            If Mayor = Array(i) Then 'La posición del array que sea igual a mayor pasará a ser 0.
                Array(i) = -32768
                exit for
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, lamentablemente ya es muy tarde, pero aun así me ayuda, enserio muchas gracias